# Hello. I am a begineer to javascript and google app script.I have done my coding to send emails by google sheets but the emails are not sending

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is my coding. Help me out.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();
   
   
var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();

//for (var i =2;i<=lr;i++){
var currentEmail = column(i,1);
var currentClass = column(i,3).getValues();
var currentName = ss.getRange(i,2).getValues();

var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{class}",currentClass);
var subjectLine = "Reminder:" + currentClass + " Upcoming Class";
MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,subjectLine,messageBody);
```

Comment: i is undefined, column is undefined ---Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

There are many issues in your code, including undefined variables (e.g. `column`, `i`), but I think you want to do the following:

Send an email for each row in `Sheet1`, taking into account that:

- `recipient` is in column `A`.
- `subject` is based on the value of column `C`.
- The message body is built by replacing the keywords `{name}` and `{class}` from a string template found in `Template!A1` with the values of column `B` and `C` respectively.

#### Code snippet:

If the above is correct, you can do the following:

```
function yourFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet1.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1; 
  var templateText = ss.getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var values = sheet1.getRange(firstRow,1,numRows,3).getValues(); // Retrieve data from all rows
  values.forEach(row => { // Iterate through each row
    var [currentEmail, currentName, currentClass] = row; // Get values from columns A-C
    var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName)
                                  .replace("{class}",currentClass);
    var subjectLine = "Reminder:" + currentClass + " Upcoming Class";
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,subjectLine,messageBody);
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Tutorial: Sending emails from a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)